# htaccess redirect with search query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have read other questions and tried a few things but nothing is happening.

I want redirect something like this

```
https://www.example.com/obs_v1/obssearch.php?cx=001670801392349880716:9zjmlwmlf9i&cof=FORID:10;NB:1&ie=UTF-8&q=xanthan+gum
```

to this (i dont care about the cx)

```
https://www.example.com/new-search/keyword/xanthan%20gum/
```

This what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=$
RewriteRule ^obs_v1/obssearch.php?cx=(.*)&q=$ /new-search/keyword/$1   [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)q=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^obs_v1/obssearch\.php$ /new-search/keyword/%1? [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```